# Установка ОС из под ОС

Tags: debian, установка, ос

Нужно сделать следующее: установить ОС Debian из под этой же ОС, т.е. я хочу подключить жесткий диск к компу, загрузиться со своего и установить на новый ЖД - ОС, как такое можно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это делается с помошью debootstrap.

Сначала форматируешь и размечаешь диск. Смонтируй в /target

```
 mkdir -p /target
 mount /dev/sdb1 /target
 debootstrap jessie /target http://deb.debian.org/debian/
```

В fstab надо добавить путь к диску, лучше через uuid (`ls -la /dev/disk/by-uuid | grep sdb`).
В /target/fstab:

```
 UUID=b674ab88-c521-47b3-b4a1-9614590482a6 / ext4 rw,defaults 0 0
```

Потом биндишь /dev/ /proc/ /sys/

```
mount -B /dev/ /target/dev
mount -B /sys/ /target/sys
mount -B /proc/ /target/proc
```

Чрутишься туда и доустанавливаешь ядро, загрузчик и десктоп если надо

```
chroot /target /bin/bash
echo nameserver 77.88.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf

apt update
apt install linux-image-amd64 tasksel grub
tasksel
grub-install /dev/sdb
```

Загрузчик ставится только вручную на нужный диск.

Не забудьте создать пользователей и установить пароль на root (или sudo):

```
apt install sudo adduser
adduser username
adduser username sudo
```

или

```
passwd root
```

Дальше выходи из chroot (контрол+d или exit) и пробуй загрузиться.

Wiki скудна на инструкции
https://wiki.debian.org/ru/Debootstrap

Подробная инструкция из мануалов
https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apds03.html.ru

Comment: В вики зато есть ссылка на полную инструкцию по установке: https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apds03.html.ru Где как раз много чего описано и в основном даже с переводом.

Comment: добавлю что статей в интернете на эту тему много.

Comment: добавил несколько моментов, без которых использовать ОС врятли получится